# DnsMasq - resolve all DNS requests to specific IP

Tags: ubuntu, dns, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04, dnsmasq

I'm trying to configure DNSMasq on Ubuntu 16.04 in order to resolve all DNS queries to a specific, fixed IP address, for all domains.

I'm attempting to set up the rules in the NetworkManager-managed DNSMasq instance (though suggestions for an alternative approach are also very welcome). I have created the file /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf:

```
local=/localnet/
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts
interface=lo
interface=eth0
address=/#/192.168.1.15
```

However, the above doesn't work. I have tried saving the config file, starting the network service then pinging an external address over ethernet, and it fails with an unknown host error, instead of resolving to the static IP I have configured.

Any idea where I've gone wrong? Does it look like the above config should work?

Comment: DNS resolution should always be interface non-specific. Interfaces are chosen by route, and route is determined by destination IP. When resolving a hostname by query, you don't know what the destination IP will be so you don't know the route. For this reason, you cannot have route specific choices for DNS resolution.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I can live without the interface specific resolution if I can get it working in general. I'll edit my question to that effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer - pretty obvious really, but hopefully someone else can learn from my silliness- the "interface" config setting tells dnsmasq which interfaces to listen on- if you have multiple instances of dnsmasq you could use the config above to specify which interfaces each instance should listen on.

However, if you have just the default dnsmasq running, you don't really want to include the interface setting, or you're telling dnsmasq not to resolve any IPs for whichever interfaces you exclude.

So I removed the "interface" settings and it worked.